# Remove fields from a json array in Python

Tags: python, json

Currently I have a function returning json via jsonify.

```
[
  {
    "hostname": "bla",
    "ipaddress": "192.168.1.10",
    "subnetmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "iloip": "192.168.1.11"
   }
]
```

I want to keep it in json format, but I want to only show the fields I choose (i.e. reduce it). For this example, I want hostname and ipaddress.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a list of dictionaries, you can iterate over the list and either use `del d["subnetmask"]` or `d.pop("subnetmask")` (assuming your dict is `d` and you want to delete `subnetmask`).

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! As a refresher, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Like, to start, do you know [how to parse a JSON string](/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json-format) and how to delete keys from a dict (or how to select keys)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
import json


response = [
    {
        "hostname": "bla",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.10",
        "subnetmask": "255.255.255.0",
        "iloip": "192.168.1.11",
    }
]
desired_keys = ["hostname", "ipaddress"]
new_response = json.dumps(
    [{key: x[key] for key in desired_keys} for x in response]
)
```

And now you have a `new_response` - valid JSON, with which you can continue to work on

Comment: I only need to show certain fields. Needs to return valid json

Comment: @Butcho, see now

Comment: @QwertYou Yup, definitely! You could improve it further if you wanted by [not repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) about the keys -- instead factoring them out into a list, like `desired_keys = ["hostname", "ipaddress"]` ... `[{k: x[k] for k in desired_keys} for x in response]`.

Comment: Added this too, thanks for the comment on the code! In addition, now the code has become flexible, and if you need to add some field for "view" or remove it, then it's much easier now

Comment: Thanks to you both

Comment: Quick question: response is already a json array, when I insert it into json.dumps, and then call jsonify, it's adding an additional double quotes around it and its refusing to pretty print. How would I fix that?

Comment: now it is the same as I wrote :)

Comment: @Butcho, you already have a valid JSON, you don't need to use `json.dumps`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
json_input = '''
[
  
  {
    "hostname": "bla",
    "ipaddress": "192.168.1.10",
    "subnetmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "iloip": "192.168.1.11"
   }
]
'''
desired_keys = {'hostname', 'ipaddress'}

json_filtered = json.dumps([{ k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if k in desired_keys} 
        for d in json.loads(json_input)])

print(json_filtered)
```

output:

```
'[{"hostname": "bla", "ipaddress": "192.168.1.10"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you want to achieve can be done with the code given below:

```py
import json

data_json = '{"hostname": "bla","ipaddress": "192.168.1.10","subnetmask": "255.255.255.0","iloip": "192.168.1.11"}'

data = json.loads(data_json)

chosen_fields = ['hostname', 'ipaddress']

for field in chosen_fields:
    print(f'{field}: {data[field]}')
```

Output:

```bash
hostname: bla
ipaddress: 192.168.1.10
```

Here what we do is we parse the stringified version of the json using the python's json module (i.e. json.loads(...)). Next decide on the fields we want to access (i.e. *chosen_fields*). Finally we iterate through the field we want to reach and get the corresponding values of the fields. This leaves the original json unmodified as you wished. Hope this helps.

---

Or else if you want these fields as a reduced json object:

```py
import json

data_json = '{"hostname": "bla","ipaddress": "192.168.1.10","subnetmask": "255.255.255.0","iloip": "192.168.1.11"}'

data = json.loads(data_json)

chosen_fields = ['hostname', 'ipaddress']

reduced_json = "{" 
for field in chosen_fields:
    reduced_json += f'"{field}": "{data[field]}", '

reduced_json = list(reduced_json)
reduced_json[-2] = "}" 
reduced_json = "".join(reduced_json)
reduced = json.loads(reduced_json)

for field in chosen_fields:
    print(f'"{field}": "{reduced[field]}"')
```

Output:

```bash
"hostname": "bla"
"ipaddress": "192.168.1.10"
```